# Why can't create a shortcut icon in start menu?

Tags: desktop

I can create a shortcut icon in the start menu for firefox:

```
sudo vim  /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Mozilla Firefox not esr 
Comment=Browse the World Wide Web
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/usr/local/bin/firefox %U
Icon=/opt/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
StartupNotify=true
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
```

In similar fashion, I want to create a shortcut icon in start menu for tor-browser too:

```
sudo vim  /usr/share/applications/start-tor-browser.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Tor Browser
GenericName=Web Browser
Comment=Tor Browser  is +1 for privacy and −1 for mass surveillance
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;Security;
Exec=sh -c '"/home/tor-browser/Browser/start-tor-browser" --detach || ([ !  -x "/home/tor-browser/Browser/start-tor-browser" ] && "$(dirname "$*")"/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach)' dummy %k
X-TorBrowser-ExecShell=./Browser/start-tor-browser --detach
Icon=/home/tor-browser/Browser/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
StartupWMClass=Tor Browser
```

Why no shortcut icon in the start menu for my tor browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is specific procedure to have it in desktop's application menu, you need to execute:

`'./start-tor-browser.desktop --register-app'`

**Note: (comments from the Tor Browser project)**

> When invoked from the **shell**, this file **must always** be in a **Tor Browser root directory**.

> When run from the file manager or desktop GUI, it is relocatable.
> After first invocation, it will update itself with the absolute path to the current Tor Browser location, to support relocation of this .desktop file for GUI invocation.

**Note:** This information can be found within *tor-browser-linux64-12.0.2_ALL.tar.xz* file, namely *start-tor-browser.desktop* file, which is part of the archive.